# ansible json_query merge 2 results

Tags: ansible

Im have a result from a Netbox server:

I want to find the next awaible vlan with the state Deprecated.

```
- name: Create Fact 
  set_fact:
    netbox_json_filter:  "{{ netbox_json.json.results | json_query('[*].vid') }}"

- debug:
    var: netbox_json_filter


- name: Create Fact2
  set_fact:
    netbox_json_filter2:  "{{ netbox_json.json.results | json_query('[*].status.value') }}" 

- debug:
    var: netbox_json_filter2
```

Is it possible to combine the 2 result or use a new query ?

{
"count": 2,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
{
"id": 4,
"url": "http://192.168.209.230:8000/api/ipam/vlans/4/",
"display": "Test VLAN (400)",
"site": null,
"group": null,
"vid": 400,
"name": "Test VLAN",
"tenant": null,
"status": {
"value": "deprecated",
"label": "Deprecated"
},
"role": null,
"description": "",
"tags": [],
"display_name": "Test VLAN (400)",
"custom_fields": {
"Jack": null
},
"created": "2021-06-19",
"last_updated": "2021-06-19T17:51:14.262534Z",
"prefix_count": 0
},
{
"id": 5,
"url": "http://192.168.209.230:8000/api/ipam/vlans/5/",
"display": "Test VLAN (401)",
"site": null,
"group": null,
"vid": 401,
"name": "Test VLAN",
"tenant": null,
"status": {
"value": "reserved",
"label": "Reserved"
},
"role": null,
"description": "",
"tags": [],
"display_name": "Test VLAN (401)",
"custom_fields": {
"Jack": null
},
"created": "2021-06-19",
"last_updated": "2021-06-19T17:59:40.343774Z",
"prefix_count": 0
}
]
}

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the simplified data

```yaml
    resutls:
      - vid: 1
        status:
          value: A
      - vid: 2
        status:
          value: B
      - vid: 3
        status:
          value: C
```

It's possible to create lists. See [MultiSelect List](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#multiselect-list), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        filter: "{{ resutls|json_query('[].[vid, status.value]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  filter:
  - - 1
    - A
  - - 2
    - B
  - - 3
    - C
```

The next option is to create dictionaries. See [MultiSelect Hash](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#multiselect-hash), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        filter: "{{ resutls|json_query('[].{vid: vid, value: status.value}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  filter:
  - value: A
    vid: 1
  - value: B
    vid: 2
  - value: C
    vid: 3
```

Comment: You're welcome. Edit your question, please. It will be closed if you leave it this way.